# Capybara test backtrace error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to use Capybara within my application. Unfortunately, the scenario I made is not run.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

feature 'User navigates to the home page' do
  p "in feature" 

  scenario 'she sees a list' do
    p "begin scenario"
  end

end
```

Only the first print is executed. Then the following error appears:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `uses_transaction?' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserNavigatesToTheHomePage:Class
 # /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:922:in `run_in_transaction?'
 # /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:935:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /Users/octavian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:824:in `before_setup'
```

Comment: In my system the `require` for capybara goes into the `spec_helper` file... and you only have `require spec_helper` in the actual feature file. thus this might be some kind of odd loading-order bug? Try that and see if it helps

Comment: Adding `require 'rails_helper'` fixed this for me.